# Android: Toast won't delay on spinner

Tags: android, spinner, handler, delay

I want to delay the toast on selected delay times like (15, 30, 60 seconds and no delay) but it won't work. Here's the code:

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
            View view, int pos, long id) {
        if(FirstLoad){
            FirstLoad = false;
            return;                         
        }
          Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "You chose " + 
              parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString()+ " to delay", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

          Message message = new Message();
          Bundle bun = new Bundle();
          bun.putString("delay", parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString());
          message.obj = bun;
          if (pos == 0) {
              handler.sendMessageDelayed(message, 0);
          }
          else if (pos == 1) {
              handler.sendMessageDelayed(message, 15000);
          }
          else if (pos == 2) {
              handler.sendMessageDelayed(message, 30000);
          }
          else if (pos == 3) {
              handler.sendMessageDelayed(message, 60000);
          }
          //handler.sendMessageDelayed(message, 15000);
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
          return;
        }
```

Help Please.

Comment: You mean: Toast not shown OR it dont obey the timing thing?

Comment: It didn't obey the timing thing.

Comment: then you should put the code for showing toast in handler. right now, whenever any item is selected from spinner it will first show the toast then send a message with a bundle in it... got my point?

Comment: Can you show me how by using my code?

Comment: Do I need to include the new Message and bundle?

Comment: @kev - look at my answer on your new question [Android: delaying toast from the send button according to spinner](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991279/android-delaying-toast-from-the-send-button-according-to-spinner/7991684#7991684).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
    final Toast toast = Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "You chose "
            + parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString() + " to delay",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

    Runnable showToastRunnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            toast.show();
        }
    };

    if (pos == 0) {
        handler.postDelayed(showToastRunnable, 0);
    } else if (pos == 1) {
        handler.postDelayed(showToastRunnable, 15000);
    } else if (pos == 2) {
        handler.postDelayed(showToastRunnable, 30000);
    } else if (pos == 3) {
        handler.postDelayed(showToastRunnable, 60000);
    }
```

Edit:

> By the way, I want to transfer this to the send button, i want to delay the toast of "Message sent" according to the delay the user chose. How should I implement it?

How are you fetching the delay? Is it something the user enters in an `EditText`?
In that case you could just get the delay like this :

```
int delay = Integer.parseInt(delayEditText.getText().toString());
```

and then use that delay amount to post the runnable to the handler like this :

```
handler.postDelayed(showToastRunnable, delay);
```

You can remove your entire if-else block in this case.

Comment: Aki Thankyou, it works fine. By the way, I want to transfer this to the send button, i want to delay the toast of "Message sent" according to the delay the user chose. How should I implement it?

Comment: Nope, the delay is via spinner, the user will choose in the spinner on how long the delay will be that's why i have if-else block. What I want now is how to send the delay in the toast of send button.

Comment: How have you populated the spinner?

Answer (score 0):

Declare your handler this way:

```
Hanlder handlder=new Handler() {

    public  void handleMessage (Message msg) {
         Toast.makeText(YOUR_ACTIVITY_CLASS_NAME.this,"You chose"+(Bundle(msg.obj)).getString("delay","DEFAULT_VALUE")+"to delay",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
    };
```

Simply, you don't have to use a bundle, but you can call msg.what=THE DELEY TIME.
Also, you can call handler.obtainMessage to get a message. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#obtainMessage%28%29
So every time you send a message, it will be handled here, and thus you call show the toast.
Sorry that I don't have Eclipse installed on this laptop, so I can not test the code. However, I believe it works.

Comment: So what you really want to do is to show a Toast after a time delay? Now the Toast shows immediately after you select something?

Comment: Yeah, I want the toast to show after the specified delay, my problem now is after selecting something it shows immediately

Comment: In general, the code is excuted line by line, so the Toast will be shown right after you select a item. You have a handler, you can implment the `handleMessage(Message msg)` method to receive the message and inside that you can show you Toast. Please see the code I added.

Answer (score 0):

```
for this you can use custom dialog and hide it after a particular time.

    class CustomDialog extends Dialog
    {
             setContentView(R.layout.dialogxml);    
         txtview=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtmsg);
    }
    Customdialog dialog= CustomDialog.show();

    dialog.hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Handler hl_DelayedToast = new Handler(); // scope global

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,View view, int pos, long id) 
{
    if(FirstLoad)
    {
        FirstLoad = false;
        return;                         
    }

    //if else logic to check the time
    // if 0
    hl_DelayedToast.postDelayed(mytoastshower,0);
    // if 1
    hl_DelayedToast.postDelayed(mytoastshower,1000);
}

public Runnable mytoastshower = new Runnable
{ 
    public void run()
    {
        Toast.show();// show the toast
    }
}
```

hope it helps.

Comment: Error on the runnable method.

Comment: i didn't check the code on compiler. its just a prototype, i just wanted to convey the logic... btw whats the error?

Comment: The Runnable thingy, once you copy the codes here to your workspace it just gives a lot of error

Comment: Do I have to put the runnel after the onitemselected? or after the onnothingselected? Do i have to include this: Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "You chose " + 
           parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString()+ " to delay", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); Message message = new Message();
       Bundle bun = new Bundle();
       bun.putString("delay", parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString());
       message.obj = bun;

Comment: Errors: 1. Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens - public void run() {:  2. Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method show() from the type Toast - Toast.show(); 3. public Runnable mytoastshower = new Runnable - Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)

Comment: The code looks like this?: public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
         View view, int pos, long id) {
  if(FirstLoad){
            FirstLoad = false;
            return;                         
  }
       Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "You chose " + 
           parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString()+ " to delay", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); if (pos == 0) {
        handler.postDelayed(mytoastshower, 0);
       }
       else if (pos == 1) {
        handler.postDelayed(mytoastshower, 15000);
       }

Comment: else if (pos == 2) {
        handler.postDelayed(mytoastshower, 30000);
       }
       else if (pos == 3) {
        handler.postDelayed(mytoastshower, 60000);
       } public Runnable mytoastshower = new Runnable
      public void run() {
            Toast.show();
      }// show the toast

     public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
       return;
     }