# Delaying toast from the send button according to spinner in Android

Tags: android, spinner, delay, toast

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android: Toast won't delay on spinner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976474/android-toast-wont-delay-on-spinner)

I want to delay the toast "Your message "message" is sent to "contact"  to appear according to the delay the user chose in the spinner. The following codes has errors (pos), here's my code:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
spinnerTimeDelay = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_delay);
spinnerTimeDelay.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        ArrayAdapter<String> aa=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,items);
        aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnerTimeDelay.setAdapter(aa);

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
            View view, int pos, long id) {
        if(FirstLoad){
            FirstLoad = false;
            return;                         
        }
Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "You chose " + 
                  parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString()+ " to delay", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
}

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
          return;
        }

btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String phoneNo = editTextRecipient.getText().toString();
                    String message = editTextNewMessage.getText().toString(); 
                    boolean split = false;

                final Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                         "Your message " + "\"" + message + "\"" + " is sent to " +"\""+ phoneNo+"\"", 
                          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);1

                Runnable showToastRunnable = new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {
                      toast.show();
                  }
              };

                if (phoneNo.length()>0 && message.length()>0)  {
                    if (pos == 0) {
                          handler.postDelayed(showToastRunnable, 0);
                      }
                      else if (pos == 1) {
                          handler.postDelayed(showToastRunnable, 15000);
                      }
                      else if (pos == 2) {
                          handler.postDelayed(showToastRunnable, 30000);
                      }
                      else if (pos == 3) {
                          handler.postDelayed(showToastRunnable, 60000);
                      }
                }

                else
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                        "Please enter both phone number and message.", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });        
    }
```

How should I declare the pos?

Comment: i can see a '1' at the end of the first Toast.

Comment: please share all relevant code . cant see variable pos and handler  here

Comment: please post the logcat error!

Comment: I've edited it, the only error is the (pos) on the method of the send button.

Comment: Instead of creating a brand new question, you should update your previous question with the commented detail on the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976474/android-toast-wont-delay-on-spinner/7991019#7991019

Comment: on which item you want to send delayed toast? button or spinner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just declare one int variable `(int count=0)` globally and store position of selected spinner's item `(count=pos)` and use that int variable in your sendButton's `onClick()`'s if-else conditions `(if(count==1))`

Try this,

```
private int count=0;
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
Handler handler = new Handler();
spinnerTimeDelay = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_delay);
spinnerTimeDelay.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        ArrayAdapter<String> aa=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,items);
        aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnerTimeDelay.setAdapter(aa);

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
            View view, int pos, long id) {

           count=pos;
        if(FirstLoad){
            FirstLoad = false;
            return;                         
        }
}

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
          return;
        }

btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String phoneNo = editTextRecipient.getText().toString();
                    String message = editTextNewMessage.getText().toString(); 
                    boolean split = false;

                final Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                         "Your message " + "\"" + message + "\"" + " is sent to " +"\""+ phoneNo+"\"", 
                          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);1

                Runnable showToastRunnable = new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {
                      toast.show();
                  }
              };

                if (phoneNo.length()>0 && message.length()>0)  {
                    if (count == 0) {
                          handler.postDelayed(showToastRunnable, 0);
                      }
                      else if (count == 1) {
                          handler.postDelayed(showToastRunnable, 15000);
                      }
                      else if (count == 2) {
                          handler.postDelayed(showToastRunnable, 30000);
                      }
                      else if (count == 3) {
                          handler.postDelayed(showToastRunnable, 60000);
                      }
                }

                else
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                        "Please enter both phone number and message.", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });        
    }
```

Comment: I wanna put a progress dialog when the user presses the send button, the progress dialog appears then goes off when the toast that the message is sent. I mean, the duration of the progress dialog is the same as the toast, how should i implement that?